# ADB is not working in android USB not recognizing

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

[image: Android Studio device list screenshot]

I added an emulator, but it didn't show up. All USB drivers are installed install but it's not showing.

When I click on ADB in the sdk this error occurs:
[image: Error: the application was unable to start correctly]

Currently I am running Android Studio 3.3.2
Operating system Windows 7

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. That's not really enough information for us to say what's going on. Have you started up your emulator and is it on the home screen? Emulators won't show up as USB devices as they're not physical devices.

Comment: emulator is not running you can see the images

Comment: Could you provide a little bit more info ? What OS are you running, which version of Android studio are you running ?

Comment: window 7 android studio 3.3.2

Comment: Connect android device and check

Comment: @ramyabr wow answer of the year.. this is the only thing that i forget...

Comment: Looks like your `adb.exe` is corrupted.